# See HTML response in Rails Ajax Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to see HTML response when I do an AJAX Reqeust, just for debug. I would like to see html instead the page content,actually I see something like this:

```
<li>something</li>
```

But I want:
Something

Don't want to see the tags, only the HTML thaht is not loading.

In PHP I can click on inspect element and see the html responses of the network reqeust without the tags. Just the html.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the developer's tab to see the request sent in AJAX, then inspect the response.

Answer (score 0):

As MrYoshiji mentioned, this is probably best handled by using the developer's console, filtering AJAX traffic, and from there inspecting the raw response. Chrome has a "Preview" tab of the response that I believe will render HTML (though I haven't tried it presonally).

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the HTML is not loading. I see the raw content instead.